# How to tell Typescript compiler to compile JSX in .ts files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some `.ts` files that has .jsx syntax in them. I want to tell `tsc` to compile my these .ts files like compiling .tsx files.

Is is possible to configure `tsc` to do that?

How can I configure vscode to support syntax highlighting for JSX syntax in these files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you must have your react code in `.tsx` files, [as the docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage):

> In order to use JSX you must do two things.
>
> 1. Name your files with a .tsx extension
> 2. Enable the jsx option

The reason for this is that in typescript you cast in this form:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

let p = <Point> {};
```

In `tsx` files however this is not possible because `<Point>` can be markup for a `Point` component.
Because of that in `tsx` files casting is not possible and you need to type assert:

```
let p = {} as Point;
```

But regular `.ts` files still support the casting form which will cause conflicts if you'll have jsx code in them.